# How can we write text on EditText Border?

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputedittext, material-components-android

[image]

How can we achieve this things in android?

InputText of EditText on Border?

Comment: This can be achieved using material library provided by google. Find more details on this link - https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#outlined-text-field

Comment: Simply apply outlined box style to _TextInputLayout_ by `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#filled-box-default)

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And apply this style:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

[image]